# Calculating values on web page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a ASP.net web page.
It is some sort of order page ...

we have table on that page.
the columns are Name of product, unit price, Quantity, Total price of the product.
there are multiple products in rows of table

The Quantity column have TextBox for inputting the value.

I have one Calculate button... on clicking that the Total Price column should display the calculated value of products.

on button click all products rows "Total Price" column should display calculated value (Quantity * UnitPrice)

I am not getting how to achieve that, as im new to ASP.NET.

Any Idea ?

Comment: what are you using asp.net controls or html controls. for asp.net you can refer using thier name and for html you have to use javascript or jquery for code

Comment: displaying the code you have developed so far will be helpful for others to suggest an answer

Comment: i have used html tags to create the table. <table></table>. but how can i achieve the displaying in table using javascript? Also i haven't write code in CodeBehind.

Comment: retag your question, add some other tags like Javascript if you, as you said, want to use javascript.

Comment: @Vijay if you are not constrained with javascript then you should use jquwery that will ease a lot of your work

Comment: Dear Amritpal, I can use anything to get the result... please suggest how we can do it... any help is welcome..

Comment: Dear All, for reference please check this site: https://www2.mcneel.com/reseller/Order-AS-V4.asp Here what happens on clicking Recalculate button? I need my webpage to work like this... I have came across this page while searching...

Answer (score 1):

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MNRcw/) I have used jQuery
[jQuery: .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Sorry Sir, I just don't getting how to do it. i want to take unit price from database and count from web page .... and on clicking calculate button i want to show result in table's column, for each row just like that site i have told. i checked your example  but nothing is happening...i have attached debug pointer but it is not even going to that point... totally confused.. might be i am doing something wrong. i'm new to asp.net and really got frustrated. please suggest how can i achieve that.

Comment: but if i have to use datagrid now then i have to replace all my Table. Also i have to fill the table partially with the fixed texts and partially with the fields from database... and also after calculation i have to modify the values in particular column cell too. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one that doesn't reach for jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/gr5Fr/25/

Comment: Sorry Sir, I just don't getting how to do it. i want to take unit price from database and count from web page .... and on clicking calculate button i want to show result in table's column, for each row just like that site i have told. i checked your example but nothing is happening...i have attached debug pointer but it is not even going to that point... totally confused.. might be i am doing something wrong. i'm new to asp.net and really got frustrated. please suggest how can i achieve that

Comment: Have a look at the `Repeater control`[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx] or the `GridView`[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.100).aspx] control to get your data on to the page.

Comment: but if i have to use datagrid now then i have to replace all my Table. Also i have to fill the table partially with the fixed texts and partially with the fields from database... and also after calculation i have to modify the values in particular column cell too. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have hard coded your table as your comments suggest then why not just do

```
int ProductOneTotal = (int)ProductOnePrice.Text * (int)ProductOneAmount.Text;
int ProductTwoTotal = (int)ProductTwoPrice.Text * (int)ProductTwoAmount.Text;

      ...and so on for each product and then.

int ProductTotal = ProductOneTotal + ProductTwoTotal + ....the rest;
```

Leaving you with ProductTotal which is the total value.